# <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2/css2.css"> not working

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to connect html with the CSS.

I've checked that:

- The stylesheet path of the css is correct, and it is: `css2/css2.css`
- The `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2/css2.css" />` code is well written and I think it is.
- I also tried to try several code editors in case it was a preview problem, I've already tried **Atom** and **brackets** and the two do not show that the CSS gets connected.

---

**HTML** code :

[image]

The html close tag is written too at the bottom.

**CSS**

[image]

[here is where the html and CSS file is placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO48E.png)

Comment: Please format your question correctly. Do not put code as images... Follow [Editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: can you make a screenshot of your project tree structure?

Comment: Stick a forward slash at the front of your `href`

Comment: Your html file is located in the folder that contains the directory css2 which contains the file css2.css? and neither the directory or file has a capital letter?

Comment: Are there any errors (404) in console?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code.  It's likely that your folder and files aren't properly structured.  Check and see what errors the console gives you.

Comment: Ok, now I have discovered what was the problem, after so much testing it seems that the correct code was <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css"/> 
I do not understand why it is not necessary to put css2/css.css instead of the above, even so, I have already discovered what was the bug and I am very happy, thank you very much for your help, the truth is that this forum is worth it, you are all very active 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your statement that css files is `css/css2.css`

so it means you should link css file by this code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css2.css" />
```

You added `css2` instead of `css` as folder name

Comment: Hello Naveed, thank you very much for your reply, I have already put the HTML and CSS  in the same folder (the folder is called css2, I was wrong to write it in the post) even so, when writing 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2/css2.css"> still does not work.

I've published an image of where I left the html file and css in the post, in case you can see where it might be failing. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Ok, now I have discovered what was the problem, after so much testing it seems that the correct code was <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css"/> 
I do not understand why it is not necessary to put css2/css.css instead of the above, even so, I have already discovered what was the bug and I am very happy, thank you very much for your help, the truth is that this forum is worth it, you are all very active 

Comment: @LuisAnaya that reason could be that your both files are in same folder. we add folder name in path if its in inner folder like home directory have index.html and there is css file which is located in home/css/style.css file. so in that case our code will be `href="css/style.css"`. anyway, let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 1):

This code will 100% work, Just make sure your HTML file and CSS2 folder need to be on same level (in same folder).

otherwise this CSS file not link to your HTML.

Comment: hello Atul, thank you very much for your help, I just put the 2 files in the same folder (css2) but still does not work... I've published an image of where I left the html file and css in the post, in case you can see where it might be failing. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Ok, now I have discovered what was the problem, after so much testing it seems that the correct code was <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css"/> 
I do not understand why it is not necessary to put css2/css.css instead of the above, even so, I have already discovered what was the bug and I am very happy, thank you very much for your help, the truth is that this forum is worth it, you are all very active 